# Bootswatch change definition of nav class from block to flex?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox, bootstrap-4, bootswatch

I am following a tutorial using `.net core`, `bootstrap` and `bootswatch`. In the tutorial, there is this menu:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a asp-controller="App" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a asp-controller="App" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
    <li><a asp-controller="App" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a asp-controller="App" asp-action="Info">Info</a></li>
</ul>
```

In bower.json, the tutorial adds bootstrap 3.3.5 and bootswatch 3.3.7. When this .net core 2 program runs, the style for nav is:

```
display: block
```

In English, the menu appears like a table with 1 column and 4 rows.

As bootstrap and bootswatch 4 are already here, I upgrade them in bower.json to 4.1.0. To my surprise, the stylr for nav is changed to:

```
display: flex
```

In English, the menu now appears as 4 columns but only 1 row.

Why does the definition of `nav` change? Is this a bug?

Comment: No it isn't a bug. Bootstrap 4 uses flexbox by default. Check the docs for a vertical nav: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#vertical

Comment: Great. That is what I am looking for. Looks like Bootstrap 4 demands more. I guess cannot assume nav means horizontal alignment. Could you please write what you have as answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: Think you will need to do a tutorial for bootstrap 4 as it uses a lot of different classes to bootstrap 3 - if you do a tutorial for bootstrap 3 using 4, a lot of the things won't work

Comment: I suggest checking the migration docs for changes between the versions: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/

Comment: Wow. I am surprised by all these information. Thanks a ton! As I am totally new to Bootstrap, I think I will do the 'latest and greatest'. Of course, I will keep that migration doc handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a bug. Bootstrap 4 now uses flexbox by default.

As it is a new major version, some things have been changed.

Here's a simple vertical nav (notice the added classes):

```
<nav class="nav flex-column">
  <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
</nav>
```

As you see you don't need a list element anymore. However if you want to use a list, check the docs.

Check the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#vertical) for more information.